# Not showing 2.5 K, show instead 2500 in the line chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Goal:
Show number that is 5214 and not 5.2 K. at line chart and its popup display.

Problem:
I tried using this code "materialOptions['vAxis']['format'] = "";" but it doesn't work.

What part of the code am I missing?

Info:
https://jsfiddle.net/x1fmz5ap/
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes

Thank you!

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line', 'corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      var button = document.getElementById('change-chart');
      var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Month');

      data.addColumn('number', "2017");
      data.addColumn('number', "2018");

      data.addRows([
        ['January',  -.5,  5005.7],
        ['Feburary',   .4,  8852.7],
        ['March',   .5,   1221],
        ['April',  2.9, 1215.3],
        ['May',  6.3, 8518.6],
        ['June',  -.5,  9635.7],
        ['Juli',   .4,  7418.7],
        ['August',   .5,   2512],
        ['September',  2.9, 1415.3],
        ['October',  6.3, 4218.6],
        ['November',  6.3, 6218.6],
        ['December',  6.3, 7518.6]        
      ]);


      var materialOptions = {
        chart: {
          title: 'Average Temperatures and Daylight in Iceland Throughout the Year'
        },
        width: 900,
        height: 500,
        series: {
          // Gives each series an axis name that matches the Y-axis below.
          0: {axis: 'Temps'}
        },
        axes: {
          // Adds labels to each axis; they don't have to match the axis names.
          y: {
            Temps: {label: 'Temps (Celsius)'}
          }
        },
        vAxis: {  }

      };



      function drawMaterialChart() {
      
      
       materialOptions['vAxis']['format'] = "";
      
      
        var materialChart = new google.charts.Line(chartDiv);
        materialChart.draw(data, materialOptions);
        button.innerText = 'Change to Classic';
        button.onclick = drawClassicChart;
      }

      drawMaterialChart();
    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
```